# jQuery Navigation using scollTop

Tags: jquery, css, html, navigation

I'm working on my personal site and I cannot for the life of me get the navigation to work properly. The idea is to have the navigation bar drop when you scroll down a bit by using the jQuery functions scrollTop and addClass. I've gotten it to work in this CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/smoGp But when I translate it to my site, something goes wrong. I can't find the glitch. Any help would be much appreciated! Here's the link to my site: http://lindseybakermedia.com/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Lindsey Baker Media</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="mainNav">
            <a href="#" id="logoLink"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Lindsey Baker Media Logo"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </nav>
        <section id="intro">
            <img src="images/top.svg" id="introTop" alt="Lindsey Baker Background Top">
            <h1>Hello, my name is <span class="introName">Lindsey Baker.</span><br>
            I am a <span class="introProfession">web designer</span> &amp; <span class="introProfession">graphic artist.</span></h1>
            <img src="images/bottom.svg" id="introBottom" alt="Lindsey Baker Background Bottom">
        </section>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="gallery">
            <h2><span class="introName">Design</span> Work</h2>
            <ul class="grid">
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/inkThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Got Ink?">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Got Ink?</h3>
                            <span>Digital Illustration</span>
                            <a href="#">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/gitThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: ASU Microsite">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>ASU Microsite</h3>
                            <span>Web Design</span>
                            <a href="#">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/disconnectThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Disconnect">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Disconnect</h3>
                            <span>Photo Manipulation</span>
                            <a href="#">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/napoleonThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Napoleon">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Napoleon</h3>
                            <span>Browser Extension</span>
                            <a href="#">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/rogueThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Rogue">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Rogue</h3>
                            <span>Print Design, Branding</span>
                            <a href="">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/backpackingThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Backpacking &amp; Adventures">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Backpacking &amp; Adventures</h3>
                            <span>Web Design, Branding</span>
                            <a href="">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/bloodhoundThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Bloodhound">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Bloodbound</h3>
                            <span>Mobile Application</span>
                            <a href="#">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/tasteThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Taste &amp; Treat">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Taste &amp; Treat</h3>
                            <span>Web Design, Branding</span>
                            <a href="#">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/thumbs/jajoThumb.png" alt="Lindsey Baker: Jajo">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Jajo</h3>
                            <span>Web Application</span>
                            <a href="">View Work</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section id="about">
            <article>
                <h2>More about <span class="introName">Lindsey</span></h2>
                <img src="images/lindsey.png" alt="Lindsey Baker">
                <div id="aboutPara">
                    <p>Lindsey Baker is currently a senior in the Graphic Information Techonology program at Arizona State University where she specializes in web development. She began freelance designing in 2012 and has begun working nationally with clients in Chicago and Denver. Recently, she co-founded a startup tech company where she has not only expanded her skills to UI/UX design, but has taken an interest in the entrepreneurial side of next curve technology. While the majority of Lindsey's professional experience lies in web development, her compelling, polished aesthetic has gained recognition through numberous art shows and publications. She is currently located in Scottsdale, Arizona where she will further her education and obtain her MS Tech in Technology through Arizona State University. In her spare time, Lindsey attends technology related events and is continuously bettering herself as a web and graphic designer.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Resume</a> / <a href="#">Contact</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
            <div id="form-div">
                <form class="form" id="form1">

                    <p class="name">
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="email">
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="text">
                        <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                    </p>


                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li id="gmail"><a href="mailto:lindseybakermedia@gmail.com">lindseybakermedia@gmail.com</a></li>
                <li id="phone"><a href="tel:4802854357">480.285.4357</a></li>
                <li id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/lbakermedia">Facebook</a></li>
                <li id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/lbakermedia">Twitter</a></li>
                <li id="linkedin"><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li id="instagram"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2014 Lindsey Baker</p>
        <a href="http://www.lindseybakermedia.com">lindseybakermedia.com</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fontsmoothie.min.js" async></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js" async></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/***** GEOGROTESQUE *****/
@import url("Geogrotesque-Thin.css");
@import url("Geogrotesque-UltraLight.css");
@import url("Geogrotesque-Light.css");
@import url("Geogrotesque-Regular.css");
@import url("Geogrotesque-Medium.css");
@import url("Geogrotesque-SemiBold.css");
@import url("Geogrotesque-Bold.css");
/***** ALL *****/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 0; }

body {
  font-family: museo300, georgia;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #222222;
  background-color: #fbfbfb; }

/***** INTRO *****/
section#intro {
  background-color: #37C697;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative; }
  section#intro h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Geogrotesque-Thin;
    padding-top: 35vh;
    padding-left: 6.5%;
    padding-right: 6.5%;
    font-size: 65px;
    line-height: 75px; }
    section#intro h1 .introProfession {
      font-family: Geogrotesque-Regular; }
  section#intro img#introTop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto; }
  section#intro img#introBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto; }

.introName {
  font-family: Geogrotesque-SemiBold; }

/***** NAV *****/
header nav.mainNav {
  padding: 10px 6.5%;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 87%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0; }
  header nav.mainNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle; }
    header nav.mainNav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-top: 40px;
      font-family: Geogrotesque-Light;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 22px; }
      header nav.mainNav ul li a:link, header nav.mainNav ul li a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #222222;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; }
      header nav.mainNav ul li a:hover, header nav.mainNav ul li a:active {
        color: #37C697; }
  header nav.mainNav a#logoLink img {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    float: left; }

header nav.sticky {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px; }

/***** GALLERY *****/
section#gallery {
  width: 100%; }
  section#gallery h2 {
    margin: 140px auto 0px;
    font-family: Geogrotesque-UltraLight;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #37C697;
    border-radius: 1px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    width: 87%; }

.grid {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center; }
  .grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative; }
  .grid figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    background-color: #ffffff; }
    .grid figure img {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      transition: transform 0.4s; }
  .grid figure:hover {
    border: 1px solid #222222; }
    .grid figure:hover img {
      transform: translateY(-50px); }
    .grid figure:hover figcaption {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0px);
      transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s; }
  .grid figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #37C697;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s; }
    .grid figcaption h3 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      color: #ffffff; }
    .grid figcaption a {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 60px; }
    .grid figcaption a:link, .grid figcaption a:visited {
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      background-color: #37C697;
      text-decoration: none; }
    .grid figcaption a:hover, .grid figcaption a:active {
      background-color: #2B9975; }

/***** ABOUT *****/
section#about {
  width: 87%;
  margin: 100px auto; }
  section#about a:link, section#about a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #37C697;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; }
  section#about a:hover, section#about a:active {
    background-color: #2B9975; }
  section#about h2 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: Geogrotesque-UltraLight;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #37C697;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -1px; }
  section#about img {
    float: left;
    width: 29.2%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 4.7%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc; }
  section#about #aboutPara {
    width: 64.5%;
    float: right; }
    section#about #aboutPara p {
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      text-align: justify; }

/***** CONTACT *****/
section#contact {
  background-color: #37C697;
  padding: 0 6.5%; }
  section#contact a:link, section#contact a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none; }
  section#contact a:hover, section#contact a:active {
    text-decoration: underline; }

#form-div {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px 0; }

.feedback-input {
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-family: museo300, georgia;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid transparent; }

.feedback-input:focus {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 3px solid #2B9975;
  color: #2B9975;
  outline: none;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px; }

.focused {
  color: #30aed6;
  border: #30aed6 solid 3px; }

/* Icons ---------------------------------- */
#name {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 2px; }

#name:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }

#email {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 2px; }

#email:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }

#comment {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 2px; }

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical; }

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  background-color: white; }

#button-blue {
  font-family: Geogrotesque-SemiBold;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2B9975;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-radius: 2px; }

#button-blue:hover {
  background-color: #222222; }

.submit:hover {
  color: #2B9975; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #form-div {
    left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%; } }
/***** FOOTER *****/
footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px 6.5%; }
  footer a:link, footer a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none; }
  footer a:hover, footer a:active {
    text-decoration: underline; }
  footer p#copyright {
    float: left; }
  footer a {
    float: right; }
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.mainNav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.mainNav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you included jquery in your site? Because in the console it says that $ is not defined!

Comment: I did, but I stupidly called jquery after I called the custom script. It works now - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which you include javascript files in the HTML matters. In your HTML, move these lines (jQuery):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

above these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fontsmoothie.min.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute your JS code before jQuery is loaded. I would swap that into

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fontsmoothie.min.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navigation.js" async></script>
```